# Eclipse BIRT Designer

Tags: reporting, birt

I am attempting to create a table with the format of information below in the reporting tool, BIRT Designer. I have labeled the images with the wanted and unwanted outputs. Currently I am running into the issue with Unwanted Output. I want to list the count of each fruit by name. The count is currently adding all of the fruit regardless of the subject.

I have a group in the table and it is grouping based on name currently.

[Unwanted Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rWRk.png)

[Wanted Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttoTM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Once you group the table, say on Region and you need aggregation of sales column:
When you are aggregating the column, make sure you select Aggregation On Group and not on Table

[image]

Hope this works!